# What do graphical icons and symbols in Android Studio mean?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

This one is not covered on the IntelliJ IDEA's [symbols help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/symbols.html). 
It can be guessed that the 'o' in the circle is related to Override methods but what about the upward arrow? And more generally where can I find any reference about meaning of these symbols that are specific to Android Studio?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrow upwards means the current method overrides another method. This icon is part of four such icons, as listed below:

[image: O with arrow up] This function overrides another.

[image: O with arrow down] This function is overridden elsewhere.

[image: I with arrow up] This function implements an interface.

[image: I with arrow down] This interface has one or more implementations elsewhere.

Combinations of these icons van occur, an overriding function can be overridden, and an implemented interface could be overridden too. As far as I am aware, no other combinations are possible.

Comment: Thank you, did you find the reference that explains such icons in Android Studio? They were not covered in IntelliJ's help page.

Comment: @Phoenix Brothers nope, just my own experience.

Comment: Intellij website has most of the meanings but still missing android specific icons. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html