# I'm getting these folders marked in color in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

[image]

Why are these folders marked in colors? Where can I find warnings or errors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio 3.3 folder icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55575449/android-studio-3-3-folder-icons)

Comment: No, The issue is the background-color - it might indicate something

Comment: Those are autogenerated folders. The content is also autogenerated. The color is to indicate exactly that.